# How to provide extra type information to generic vector processor

Tags: rust

`getter` calls traits to pull the generic vector type:

```
fn getter<T>(sin: &str) -> Result<Vec<T>, Error> where T: GenVecStruct
```

I'd expect the compiler to not care about the commented code (line 37) in the handler below, as it works fine with lines 42, 43 and 44**.

```
 33 fn process<F>(input: &InType, mut callback: F) where F: FnMut(OutType), {
 34     if let Ok(data) = getter("two B") {
 35         match input {
 36             InType::SomeInA => for v in data { callback(OutType::OutA(v)); }
 37             // InType::SomeInB => for v in data { callback(OutType::OutB(v)); },
 38             _ => (),
 39         };
 40     }
 41
 42     callback(OutType::OutA(A{a:1}));    //No problem here
 43     callback(OutType::OutB(B{b:1.}));   //No problem here
 44     callback(OutType::Note);            //No problem here either
 45 }
```

Compiling with **L37** produces following error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types  
--> src/main.rs:37:71  
   | 
37 |             InType::SomeInB => for v in data { callback(OutType::OutB(v)); },
   |                                                                       ^ expected struct `B`, found struct `A`
```

### **Questions:**

1. Is following reasoning accurate:  if `getter` produces a generic `Vec<T>`, the following match needs extra type information.
2. Using generics, what's the best way to inject extra type information to `processor`?  *(macros - as worst case solution)*

[Full example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ae0ad4c0b62615e669e40884a5bd1550):

```
pub enum Error {E1,}

pub trait GenVecStruct where Self: Sized, 
{
    fn to_vec_of_t(s: &str) -> Result<Vec<Self>, Error>;
}

enum InType { SomeInA, SomeInB, }
enum OutType { OutA(A), OutB(B), OutE(Error), Note,}
struct A { a: i32, }
struct B { b: f64, }

impl GenVecStruct for A {
    fn to_vec_of_t(_s: &str) -> Result<Vec<A>, Error> {
        Ok(vec![A { a: 1 }, A { a: 2 }, A { a: 3 }])
    }
}

impl GenVecStruct for B {
    fn to_vec_of_t(_s: &str) -> Result<Vec<B>, Error> {
        Ok(vec![B { b: 9. }, B { b: 8. }, B { b: 6. }])
    }
}

fn getter<T>(sin: &str) -> Result<Vec<T>, Error> where T: GenVecStruct,
{
    match T::to_vec_of_t(sin) {
        Ok(r) => Ok(r),
        Err(_) => Err(Error::E1),
    }
}

fn process<F>(input: &InType, mut callback: F) where F: FnMut(OutType),
{
    if let Ok(data) = getter("two B") {
        match input {
            InType::SomeInA => {
                for v in data {
                    callback(OutType::OutA(v));
                }
            }
fn process<F>(input: &InType, mut callback: F) where F: FnMut(OutType),
{
    if let Ok(data) = getter("two B") {
        match input {
            InType::SomeInA => for v in data{ callback(OutType::OutA(v)); },
         // InType::SomeInB => for v in data{ callback(OutType::OutB(v)); },
            _ => (),
        };
    };

    callback(OutType::OutA(A { a: 1 })); //No problem here
    callback(OutType::OutB(B { b: 1. })); //No problem here
    callback(OutType::Note); //No problem here either
}

fn main() {
    let v = InType::SomeInB;
    process(&v, |p| {
        match p {
            OutType::OutA(_) => println!("someIn A"),
            OutType::OutB(_) => println!("someIn B"),
            OutType::OutE(_) => println!("err"),
            OutType::Note => println!("Note"),
        };
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example is a far cry from a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Following the [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can drastically reduce your original code:

```
trait T {}

struct A;
impl T for A {}

struct B;
impl T for B {}

fn use_a(_: A) {}
fn use_b(_: B) {}

fn getter<T>() -> T {
    unimplemented!()
}

fn process() {
    let data = getter();

    if true {
        use_a(data);
    } else {
        use_b(data);
    }
}
```

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:21:15
   |
21 |         use_b(data);
   |               ^^^^ expected struct `B`, found struct `A`
```

Notably, if you swap the order of the method calls, you'll get a related but different error:

```
fn process() {
    let data = getter();

    if true {
        use_b(data);
    } else {
        use_a(data);
    }
}
```

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:22:15
   |
22 |         use_a(data);
   |               ^^^^ expected struct `A`, found struct `B`
```

Rust is a **statically typed language**, which means that every variable must have a single known type when the code is compiled. That's not possible with your code; you want `data` to be *either* the type `A` or `B` depending on what some future conditional will do. To the compiler, there's no difference between what you wrote and this more obviously incorrect code:

```
fn process() {
    let data = getter();

    use_a(data);
    use_b(data);
}
```

Type inference has seen that one call requires that `data` be of type `A`, so that happens to be the type that was chosen. That type then fails when it is expected to be `B`.

Instead, call the `getter` function inside of each conditional arm, creating two separate variables:

```
fn process() {
    if true {
        let data = getter();
        use_a(data);
    } else {
        let data = getter();
        use_b(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: for the 2nd question, is there a way to solve it with generics ?